# Executing sqlite3 query in bash

Tags: bash, sqlite, posix

Executing in bash

```
sqlite3 database.db 'select * from databases'
```

gives me good output, but unfortunately when I would like to create a query from a variable `sqlite3` doesn't want to cooperate.

For example:

```
cmd="select * from databases"
cmd1="sqlite3 database.db"
cmd2="'select * from databases'"
echo $($cmd1 \'$cmd\')
echo $($cmd1 '$cmd')
echo $($cmd1 $cmd)
echo $($cmd1 $cmd2)
echo `$cmd1 $cmd2`
```

None of above works. I would like to have a function which would execute just query like "select * from databases".

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Comment: Does this work? `query="select * from databases";
result=$(sqlite3 database.db "$query");
echo "$result"`.

Comment: You said "none works" - what kind of results do you get?

Comment: Maybe just don't bother using single quotes and use double quotes instead?

Comment: echo ".q" | sqlite3 -csv -noheader -cmd "select * from databases;" database.db

Comment: Why would you write `echo $(someCommand)`? Do you want to remove newlines and expand `*`? If not, then simply write `$cmd1 "$cmd"`.

Answer (score 9):

Your trouble is *word splitting*. When you run this:

> ```
> sqlite3 database.db $sql
> ```

The shell splits `$sql` to words. But `sqlite3` expects the SQL command as a single parameter. To prevent word splitting, you must enclose `$sql` in double-quotes:

```
sqlite3 database.db "$sql"
```

If you want to store the `sqlite3 database.db` in a variable called `cmd`,
you can, and write:

```
$cmd "$sql"
```

The shell will split `$cmd` to words, and in this case you want that.
You want the shell to see the `sqlite3` command, and another word `database.db` as the first argument. That's way we don't enclose `$cmd` in double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this approach:

```
cmd1="sqlite3 database.db"
cmd2="select * from databases"
$cmd1 "$cmd2"
```

I've just tried - it works for me:
[image]